Download and merge pdf in nodejs
I am trying to download a pdf and then merge it using pdf-lib in nodejs.
The pdf is being merged and I am getting total of 8 pages 4 pages each the problem is the pages are blank.
The same thing I tried with downloading with stream the pdf is downloading with the correct content.
I don't want to use any third party library for downloading.
I think I am missing something.
The code is given below.
async function downloadPdfBuffer(url, outputPath){
    logger.info({message: 'downloadPdfBuffer PDF', url, outputPath});
    try {
        const response = await httpRequestService.createAxiosConfigAndSend({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        })
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error({message: 'Error downloading PDF:', error});
        throw error;
    }
};


async function downloadAndmergePdf(pdfLinks){
    const maxTwoPdfs = _.slice(pdfLinks,0,2);
    const allPdfs = maxTwoPdfs.map(async pdfLink => {
        const pdfNameArr = pdfLink.split('?')[0].split('/');
        const pdfName = pdfNameArr.pop();
        return downloadPdfBuffer(pdfLink,pdfName);
        // return await join(process.cwd(), pdfName)
    });
    const settledPromises = await Promise.allSettled(allPdfs);
    const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create(); 
    const mergedPdfPromises = settledPromises.map(async buff => {
        if(buff.status === 'fulfilled'){
                const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(Buffer.from(buff.value,'binary'),{ignoreEncryption:true}); 
                const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
                copiedPages.forEach((page) => {
                     mergedPdf.addPage(page); 
                }); 
            // }    
        }
    })
    await Promise.all(mergedPdfPromises);
    const buf = await mergedPdf.save();   
    fs.writeFileSync('new.pdf',buf);
}

downloadAndmergePdf(['https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf','https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf'])


I can not understand the problem, I have tried with multiple things like writing it with Buffer after converting to base64, Converting to binary and then writing it.
Nothing seems to work.
I have also tried
const response = await httpRequestService.createAxiosConfigAndSend({
             method: 'GET',
             url: url, responseType:'arraybuffer'
})

and then writing it to file.
const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(response.data,{ignoreEncryption:true}); 
also
const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(Buffer.from(response.data,'binary'),{ignoreEncryption:true}); 

If you add responseType:'arraybuffer' to axios request, the problem is not with your code, but with sample documents, which have a restriction that interferes with pdf-lib.
If you use some other samples and responseType:'arraybuffer', the code works:
const response = await httpRequestService.createAxiosConfigAndSend({
             method: 'GET',
             url: url, responseType:'arraybuffer'
})

//...

// samples without restrictions
downloadAndmergePdf(['https://file-examples.com/storage/fe83e1f11c664c2259506f1/2017/10/file-example_PDF_500_kB.pdf','https://file-examples.com/storage/fe83e1f11c664c2259506f1/2017/10/file-example_PDF_500_kB.pdf'])


What can I do to solve the problem.

well, just use documents/samples that don't have restrictions, like suggested in my code. did you try running my code?

do you want to be able to merge these exact documents, from adobe website..?

The problem is the specific pdf that I am merging, also has this problem, this is just a sample document which has this problem.
I tried downloading the document and writing it to the disk it gives blank pages.

did you add responseType:'arraybuffer'? My code works fine for me, did you try it? inspect the documents with some reader, perhaps they have some restrictions or something
